# Responsive Media Queries CSS Standard 2022

Tags: html, css, responsive

First, thanks for reading my post.

I'm using bootstrap 5 and I would like to use the below media queries for my HTML templates.
So, my question is:

1. Do I need to add any other media queries?
2. Or do I need to remove any queries from the list?
3. Is this media query okay as ThemeForest standard or 2022 commonly used devices standard?
   Please check the below code.

   @media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
   @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {}

Thanka again.
FARUK AHMED

Comment: Is it possible to explain why you would like to play/edit with the media queries? Since you are using Bootstrap, then everything you need is already implemented and extra even. It would be great to understand more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

website themes that are not mobile-friendly in themeforest standards cannot be sold. If you're using Bootstrap, you already have everything you need. I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the media queries list is okay for my HTML templates. Thanks for your reply.